# TestIds softbin algorithm doesn't handle single and double digit hardbins

Tags: origen-sdk

I am using the softbin algorithm ([docs](https://github.com/Origen-SDK/test_ids#assigning-a-template)) for a test module that has hardbins 5, 11, and 16.  When I use `:bbxxx`, everything works for hardbins 11 and 16 but for 5 it only gives a single softbin and never increments the softbin on subsequent tests using this call.

```
TestIds.allocate(t, test_method_params)
```

I tried to use `:bxxx` and got this error:

```
APPLICATION CALL STACK
----------------------
Bin number (11) overflows the softbin number algorithm (bxxx)
```

If I change hardbin 5 to 14 it works.  Shouldn't `:bbxxx` handle the case where the hardbin is a single digit and adjust accordingly?

regards

Comment: It should, I would change this to a Github bug ticket

Comment: @Ginty When i switched to the new branch 'leading_counter' it worked.

Comment: Excellent, well I'll go and release that right now then!

Answer (score 0):

A [new version of the Origen test_ids gem](https://github.com/Origen-SDK/test_ids/releases/tag/v1.0.0) fixes this issue.